# Separate Ketchup Bottles

Tags: food, meat-and-milk

Does one have to keep separate ketchup bottles for meat and dairy? (and why or why not?)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44480

Comment: Do you think that ketchup bottles would be different from any other bottles of condiments. If not, consider not limiting the question to ketchup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is commendable to use separate ketchup and mustard containers for meat and dairy but it's usually not required as long as it does not touch the foods directly. If you use one container you should use squeeze type bottles, so care can be taken that the bottle doesn't touch the food on the plate. Since it does not directly touch the food it does not become an issue unless there are small children in the home who will put the nozzle in the food leading to direct touching rendering the bottle Fleishig or Milchig depending on what it touched.

Comment: There was discussion in achronim about separate salt cellars, but those are salt cellars, in which you dip your food (and food gets left behind), not salt SHAKERs.  There's a discussion about "nitzok v'hevel" connecting even a shaker to the pot below it, but that's regarding tum'a; vis-a-vis kashrus, this seems to not be the accepted halacha.

Comment: Can you bring a source?

Comment: R' Dovid Miller's mp3 on yutorah from one of his hilchos basar b'chalav shiurim.

Comment: yknow, although m'din one is not required as our salt shakers are closed, it would still be recommended. i have a friend who decided that it was too big of a chumra - until his 6yr old kid, while salting the cholent dropped the whole salt shaker in!
guess what - now he has separate ones!

Answer (score 2):

Source for it being an issue: [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah Siman 105:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4309) in the Rema, where he discussed pouring oil onto a candle made out of non-kosher fats.  Both the Shach and the Taz discuss this idea of nitzuk chibur (pouring creates a connection).

Comment: Hey @AlwaysLearning, I can kinda see where you're going with this, but perhaps you can expand it further. Perhaps include more of an explanation of nitzuk chibur and how it applies to ketchup bottles. Thanks!