# Are separate condiments/containers needed for meat and dairy?

Tags: halacha, food, meat-and-milk

When eating a dairy meal and you use the salt/pepper shakers then meat dishes are brought out do you have to switch the condiment containers too?

Likewise when cooking with dairy and using your spice containers do you have to have a separate spice set for cooking with meat?

What is the halacha on this?

Comment: [ShA YD 95:5,7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%94#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96)

Comment: When cooking a concern of Zeiya is present when pouring directly over the pot when the fire.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1842

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  The information there helped as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Halachically Speaking by Rabbi Moishe Dovid Lebovits](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_8_Issue_4.pdf)

> The Rama says that the minhag is to have separate salt utensils for
>   meat and for dairy. The reason is that some food particles remain when
>   the food is dipped into the salt, and one may inadvertently mix milk
>   and meat.The poskim say that this halacha applied in the times when
>   salt was placed in open utensils. **Today, however, we use saltshakers,
>   and this reason does not apply. Therefore, two separate saltshakers
>   are not necessary.** When children are in a household, one should have
>   two separate saltshakers, since they stick the saltshaker into the
>   food. [Ed. Note: If one pours salt from a shaker into a hot meat or
>   dairy food cooking on the fire or just removed, it is best to use the
>   shaker only with that type of food.] Some are careful to always have
>   two separate saltshakers. If one puts salt from a fleishig saltshaker
>   on dairy food or vice versa, (even when there are children in the
>   household) then the food may be eaten. It is best to try to remove the
>   salt from the food.

This is based on Rabbi Yisrael Belsky Shlita, Kaf HaChaim 31, Badi Hashulchan 88:31, [Rivevos Efraim 5:514](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1086&pgnum=406), Yalkut Yosef page 346, Piskei Halacha Kashrus page 25:21